# Capistrano 3.x running a task programatically from ruby

Tags: ruby, capistrano

Im trying to run a capistrano 3.x task from a ruby script.

I dive into the docs and in older versions of capistrano (2.x) you have Capistrano::CLI interface to access and execute tasks.

In newer versions this module seems to be gone, i can't find anything similar.

I was trying with Capistrano::DSL without no luck.

To make it clear, im looking something like this:

```
require 'capistrano/all'

Capistrano::CLI.invoke(stage, task)
```

Any clue ??

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved, this is what i did,

I used the Capistrano::Application.invoke({task}) method

For capistrano 3.8.2

```
require 'capistrano/all'
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

stages = "production"
set :application, 'my_app_name'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:capistrano/capistrano.git'
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/'
set :stage, :production
role :app, %w{www}
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }

Capistrano::Application.invoke("common:ntp")
```

Hope it helps.